# How can I share my screen with Skype for Linux 5.3?

Tags: skype

How can I share my screen via Skype 5.3? The “+” menu contains only two item: adding another communication participant and changing the audio and video settings. Nothing about screen sharing. Is this feature still not implemented? This would be very bad, as screen sharing is crucial for me, and Skype 4.3 will stop working in 3 days.

Comment: Since this was posted, the Microsoft Skype has been caught up to match Skype for Windows in features and appearance.  Has anyone tested this recently, to add new answers?

Comment: Screen sharing has been working for me for quite some time now. I’m using the current Skype for Linux 8.51.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> "Skype for Linux Beta currently lacks the support for group video calling and outgoing screen sharing. We are working hard to add these features for you as soon as possible."
>
> From [Skype.com](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34656/more-information-about-skype-for-linux-beta).

Teamviewer is a good screen sharing app IME but has had security issues. AnyDesk is [recommended on alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?platform=linux).

Comment: Google hangouts also works well with ubuntu.

Comment: Can you guys confirm Skype still doesn't support desktop sharing? Does Google Hangouts support desktop sharing?

Comment: Currently, terrible situation for Skype users with Linux...
16th Nov 2017, and today's skypeforlinux 8.10.0.4 does not support screen sharing, after skype 4.3 cutout.

Comment: @rpmcruz, yes Google Hangouts does support desktop sharing

Comment: Today (August 2018) the linux client does not seem to be able to share the screen. At least I could not find a way to share my screen. I am unsure if it is possible to view the screen of an other skype user (who uses Windows).

Answer (score 0):

https://appear.in/ now being replaced by https://whereby.com/ works for me on linux (fedora) in firefox, opera and google-chrome. It includes screen sharing, and in my experience is simpler and more effective than skypeforlinux. It uses peer to peer connections. I can't comment on security. It's free for basic use, but more facilities are available to subscribers who pay. I've used only the free service, including giving remote lectures with questions from the audience.

Comment: https://meet.jit.si/ has screen sharing, as do most video calling apps now.